# Usando o angular e ionic, como faço para percorrer um vetor somando uma variavel de um objeto?

Tags: angularjs, ionic, angularjs-scope, angularjs-services

Eu tenho um vetor de objetos com preços, nome do produto..., após o cliente ter clicado em um produto eu passo ele para outra lista, de pedidos, após ser feito isso preciso fazer com que eu some os preços dos produtos da lista e me retorne um total  cada vez q um novo produto é adicionado e caso removido precisa ser subtraído do total. Estou utilizando $scope nessa aplicaçao, pois é um app ionic.

Estou utilizando um service para preencher essa lista pq eu tenho mais dois vetores q tem as msm especificações mas dividir os produtos em mais dois vetores para organizar melhor e foi a solução que encontrei. Mas n estou entendendo o que ele representa muito bem no código.

```
.controller('pedidoCtrl', function($scope, produtoService) {

    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.items = produtoService.getProdutos();

    $scope.deleteItem = function(item){
        $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
    };
})

.service('produtoService', [function(){
    var produtosLista = [];

    var addProduto = function(produto) {
        produtosLista.push(produto);
    };

    var getProdutos = function(){
        return produtosLista;
    };

    return {
        addProduto: addProduto,
        getProdutos: getProdutos,
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Sua pergunta não está bem clara. Tente clicar em [edit] e melhorá-la um pouco. Explique com calma: **1.** O que você pretende fazer? (O resultado esperado) **2.** Qual é **exatamente** o problema que estás tendo? **3.** Você já tentou fazer algo? Se sim, o que? E, como? E qual foi o problema que teve com a sua tentativa?

Comment: vlw pela dica, tentei melhorar